# Spring singleton scope isn't working in web application

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to understand the scopes in spring in the web context.
I have bean called player which I have defined in the configuration file as below :

```
<bean id="playerBean" class="com.anvesh.model.Player" scope="singleton"/>
```

Then I have servlet which acts as RequestController (All the submit requests from jsps will route through this servlet). In this servlet, I  am initializing the spring configuration file as below :

```
XmlWebApplicationContext ctx = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
ctx.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/WebAppContext.xml");
ctx.setServletContext(getServletContext());
ctx.refresh();
```

This servlet handles two types of requests
1) loginValidate
2) getFutureMatches

when the "loginValidate" is invoked I am creating player bean and control will go the PlayerHomePage.jsp(as in below)

```
player = ctx.getBean("playerBean",Player.class);
player.setName("Anveshan");
player.setExp(10);
player.setId(3175);
player.setQualification("B.Tech");
System.out.println("In the validate Login :"+player);
response.sendRedirect("/SpringRefernce_Scope/Jsp/PlayerHomePage.jsp");
```

In the PlayerHomePage.jsp, I invoking "getFutureMatches" action. So again control will come to RequestController and in here, I am trying to access player bean like below

```
player = ctx.getBean("playerBean",Player.class);
```

But I am getting player as null.

Since I have defined the playerBean as singleton, once it is instantiated, same bean should be returned whenever it is invoked at other places. This is happening correctlywhen I use ApplicationContext.but when I use XmlWebApplicationContext,the singleton bea isn't maintained.

--- When I use scope as **session/application** then my player bean is NOT NULLIFIED  even in the  "getFutureMatches" action.  I am able to get Player object which is initalized in prevous request. But I am not able to understand why singletion isn't doing that. Please help me.

Please note that I am not using spring-mvc. my web.xml entries are as below :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>requestController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.anvesh.servlet.RequestController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>requestController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RequestController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: You will get a new bean if you are creating a new `Context`. The original bean will be returned only if same context is used.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have kept initialization of config file code in the post method, XmlWebApplicationContext  is initialized every time post method is invoked. Since every time refresh() is invoked, singleton objects are lost. I have moved the below initialization code to the init() method of the servlet. Now refresh() is not invoked everytime post() is called and hence singleton object is retained.

```
XmlWebApplicationContext ctx = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
ctx.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/WebAppContext.xml");
ctx.setServletContext(getServletContext());
ctx.refresh();
```

I still don't understand how session objects are maintained even though ctx.refresh() everytime.

Comment: Well actually beans aren't destroyed you get new ones each time you create a new context. So each time you will get all new beans. Instead of doing the loading yourself I would suggest removing that code and simply register a `ContextLoaderListener` in your web.xml which loads the configuration. In your code you can then simply lookup the context. Also your code seems flawed as the `Player` is a singleton all users of your website share the same instance. I don't think that is your intended usage.

Comment: Thanks Deinum, I will use ContextLoaderListener as you have mentioned....Above code is just sample code I have written to test singleton request and session scopes and that why I have made player as singleton. it is not a production code.